# Is focus dependent upon time?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, psychology

I have been contemplating on various things happening around me and was categorising them on the basis of how much focused I am and also considering the time of day, the question which comes up is how can focus on something be determined and is it dependent on the time frame?

[here](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/psychology/higgins/research.html) I found some information about how focus deals with accessibility and shared reality

Comment: Are these questions about cognitive science or philosophy?

Comment: This looks like a personal productivity question to me. Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_and_motion_study

Answer (score 2):

This video: [Youtube: RSA Animate: The Divided Brain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFs9WO2B8uI) could help.

Basically you have a right hemisphere which just notices movement and is at one with the environment. I myself have noticed that when I'm in "right brain mode" I "function" according to thresholds. I.e. I go eat when I'm hungry vs it's 12 o'clock and I need to eat.

So the focus would either be on the details (left brain) or the whole (right brain).

The more you focus on the details, the slower time becomes, especially if nothing changes.

If you focus on the whole and you being a part of it, evolving with it you are not noticing time or details.

There is a concept called [Wikipedia:flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_%28psychology%29) that talks about this state.